# adb error: unable to parse adb version

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, adb

Is there anyone who has had any problems using WIN7 and Eclipse?

Everytime Eclipse starts this error always comes up: `UNABLE TO PARSE ADB VERSION`

If you try and run/debug the app from within WIN7,

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2010-01-29 19:00:17 - app name] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2010-01-29 19:00:17 - app name] Please ensure that adb is correctly
located at 'C:\Android\tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Adb is located at `C:\Android\tools\adb.exe`, and can be
executed from the cmd line.  Tried quitting eclipse and WIN7 and
restarted.  Ran `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server`

```
daemon not running...
starting it now.
daemon started successfully.
```

start eclipse, and then that's when the error comes up.  This is
driving us crazy.

So, if by chance there is anyone else using WIN7 professional version
to develop on and has encountered this problem with `adb` and found a solution, please post it.

Comment: Some others seem to have similar problems on Windows 7, e.g. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=552673 -- Possibly a permissions issue? ADB allows Eclipse to talk to it by listening on a local TCP socket (port 5037) over TCP; could there be some sort of permissions or local firewall issue?

Comment: I run Win7 with Eclipse/Android on 3 machines and have not seen this error so whatever it is does not hit all Win7 setups (using Win7 Ultimate).

Answer (score 3):

I turned off Defense module in COMODO and the same problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I run Win7 Ulitmate with Eclipse Indigo 7.1 and Android SDK R15 for Windows. This fix should pertain only to those who have comodo Internet Security installed.
Turning off the Defense module in Comodo worked also but instead of turning off the Defense module in Comodo, I added C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe to safe programs. adb.exe was in the Sandbox and was marked as unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing ADB.exe through Windows Firewall solved this error on my machine.